# UIButtons with anchor style auto layout constraints not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I have a subview added this way:

```
dailyButtonView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
dailyButtonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


dailyWeeklyButtonViewContainer.addSubview(dailyButtonView)

let centerX_d = dailyButtonView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(dailyWeeklyButtonViewContainer.centerXAnchor)
let centerY_d = dailyButtonView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(dailyWeeklyButtonViewContainer.centerYAnchor)
let width_d = dailyButtonView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(dailyWeeklyButtonViewContainer.widthAnchor)
let height_d = dailyButtonView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(dailyWeeklyButtonViewContainer.heightAnchor)
dailyButtonViewCenterX = centerX_d
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([centerX_d,centerY_d,width_d,height_d])
```

And immediately afterwards, I want to add six `UIButton` (same size and equal spacing) so I did this:

```
let dayButtonSide = self.dailyButtonView.frame.height * 0.6   
let dayDistance = (self.dailyButtonView.frame.width - dayButtonSide * 7) / 8.0
for index in 0...6{
    let temp = UIButton()
    temp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    temp.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    dailyButtonView.addSubview(temp)
    var test = CGFloat(index) * (dayButtonSide / 2)
    test += CGFloat(index + 1) * dayDistance - (dailyButtonView.bounds.width / 2)
    let centerX_t = temp.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(dailyButtonView.centerXAnchor, constant: test)
    let centerY_t = temp.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(dailyButtonView.centerYAnchor)
    let width_t = temp.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(nil, constant: dayButtonSide)
    let height_t = temp.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(nil, constant: dayButtonSide)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([centerX_t, centerY_t, width_t, height_t])
```

However, the buttons are not showing in simulation, even though there is not error or warning in the log.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem is with this line: `let dayButtonSide = self.dailyButtonView.frame.height * 0.6`. Because I called this function in `viewDidLoad`, the `dailyButtonView` wasn't laid out that this point.